# OpenLayers: How to hover over a raster (GeoTIFF) layer and return pixel value

Tags: openlayers, raster, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

How can I create a tooltip or mouse-over hover to return real data pixel values from a raster GeoTIFF source in Open Layers?

Thanks.

Comment: Fro calculated values https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-math.html or for raw data https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-stretch-forked-prc32e?file=/main.js